# Can anybody tell me why I have 12 wires in light box?

Tags: electrical

There’s are 8 brown wires, 2 black wires and 2 red.

I’m just trying to hook up a light fixture.

[image]

Comment: A few pictures of the junction box would be helpful.  Did you take pictures before you disconnected anything?

Comment: I messed up and didn’t take pictures. Let me see if it will upload

Comment: Can you get us better quality pictures of the inside of the box please?

Comment: It appears that there was a light fixture installed there previously,  have you tried hooking it back up the way the previous one was hooked up?

Comment: Yeah , the light hooked up to only 2 wires + ground.  There is no reason to care about any other wires.  Let 'em pass through the box if they want to :)

Comment: Your "brown" wires appear to be aged white wires, not that it matters too much if you follow the advice to hook up the fixture like the previous one an ignore the rest of the wires.

Answer (score 2):

3 supply, 3 supply to next light, 3 for switch, and possibly 3 for a duplicate fitting controlled by the switch.

As other comments said, just use the connections you need and leave the others alone.

Answer (score 2):

With old wiring, it's hard to say what's what.  In old houses it was common to feed the light with power, and feed the power to the switch.  The other wires could be anything from an outlet on the same circuit, a light on the same switch, a light on a different switch, or a completely different circuit that just uses the box as a junction.

I'd agree with the common advice of just ignoring the extra, and hooking it up like it was originally.

If you're really curious, you'd have to get out voltage testers and turn off circuits and switches, disconnect wires and walk around the house to see what does/doesn't work to know what's going on.  Unless you're doing a larger re-wiring project this is unlikely to be of any value.